# Windows 10 installation problems on ThinkPad T520

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, thinkpad

I bought an used ThinkPad T520 that came with Windows 7 from the previous owner. So I got it home, installed Linux Mint, and everything went fine, but I think I will need to use Windows. So I created a bootable pendrive and tried to install Windows 10. I managed to boot into the installation, erase the drive, and everything went fine until it had to reboot. When it reboots, it shows the loading icon with the Windows logo, then a window with the message "Windows setup could not configure to run on this computer's hardware" blinks for half a second and the laptop powers off. I booted from Mint and managed to get these logs:

setuperr.log

```
2022-06-17 22:55:55, Error      [0x060126] IBS    CallBack_ImageWasSelectedInUi: An error occurred while removing the MultiEdition key from the blackboard.[gle=0x00000490]
2022-06-17 23:14:42, Error                 SYSPRP ActionPlatform::DeleteValue: Error from RegOpenKeyExW on key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\Sysprep\OfflineState\Specialize; dwRet = 0x13
2022-06-17 23:14:42, Error                 SYSPRP SysprepSession::Execute: Win32 error (19), could not execute actions
2022-06-17 23:14:42, Error                 SYSPRP RunPlatformActions:Failed while executing Sysprep session actions; dwRet = 0x13
2022-06-17 23:14:42, Error      [0x0f0435] SYSPRP Callback_Specialize: An error occurred while either deciding if we need to specialize or while specializing; dwRet = 0x13[gle=0x00000013]
```

setupact.log

```
2022-06-17 23:14:42, Info                  SYSPRP Finished AppxPreRegisterPackage for all packages.
2022-06-17 23:14:42, Info                  SYSPRP GenerateBytecodeForPackages completed with 0x0.
2022-06-17 23:14:42, Info                  SYSPRP Exiting AppxSysprepSpecializeOnline with 0x0.
2022-06-17 23:14:42, Info                  SYSPRP ActionPlatform::LaunchModule: Successfully executed 'AppxSysprepSpecializeOnline' from C:\Windows\System32\AppxSysprep.dll
2022-06-17 23:14:42, Error                 SYSPRP ActionPlatform::DeleteValue: Error from RegOpenKeyExW on key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\Sysprep\OfflineState\Specialize; dwRet = 0x13
2022-06-17 23:14:42, Error                 SYSPRP SysprepSession::Execute: Win32 error (19), could not execute actions
2022-06-17 23:14:42, Error                 SYSPRP RunPlatformActions:Failed while executing Sysprep session actions; dwRet = 0x13
2022-06-17 23:14:42, Info                  SYSPRP Callback_Specialize: Internal Providers Specialized Failed. System can't proceed to handle Internal Providers
2022-06-17 23:14:42, Info                  SYSPRP Callback_Specialize: Specialize return: [19]
2022-06-17 23:14:42, Warning               SYSPRP Callback_Specialize: Couldn't delete InstallDriveTrusted registry value; Error = 0x13.
2022-06-17 23:14:42, Error      [0x0f0435] SYSPRP Callback_Specialize: An error occurred while either deciding if we need to specialize or while specializing; dwRet = 0x13[gle=0x00000013]
2022-06-17 23:14:42, Info       [0x0640ae] IBSLIB PublishMessage: Publishing message [A Instala\E7\E3o do Windows n\E3o p\F4de configurar o Windows para ser executado no hardware do computador.]
```

I tried searching for some terms found on the logs but couldn't find any good results. I saw some places saying it's a driver issue, but I'm not sure how I would update any drivers without an OS. What could possibly be happening here and how can I fix it? I can provide more information if needed. [Full logs here](https://pastebin.com/qEckzMMV)

Things I've tried:

- Trying to install again (more than 10 times at this point)
- Using Ventoy instead of the Windows Media Creation Tool
- Using Rufus
- Switching SATA mode from AHCI to Compatibility
- Trying to install Home edition instead of Pro
- Physically disabling Wi-Fi
- Using another pendrive

Comment: Did you download the Windows install files from Microsoft's website?

Comment: Use the Microsoft media creation tool

Comment: I did use Microsoft's Media Creation Tool.